# I have a problem with OpenTok and Nexmo API

Tags: laravel, api, vonage, dialing

I have a problem with OpenTok and Nexmo API. I am trying to connect to Nexmo phone conference using OpenTok. In order to connect to correct conference I need to pass the conference session id somehow. And here is where problem begins. I am tryting to pass custom header with session id in it using OpenTok's dial() function. But once OpenTok sends a request to Nexmo the custom header is not present on the server holding a call. Is it possible to make Nexmo pass my custom header with its data?
Kind regards

Comment: perhaps include a code sample of exactly what you've got so far

Comment: we are using official documentation from here https://github.com/opentok/opentok-nexmo-sip/tree/master/Dial-In-Conference